# Ridiculously slow USB transfer speeds

Tags: performance

I'm attempting to transfer a 1.4 GB file to a USB flash drive, and I'm getting speeds of only around 600-700 kbps. I've tried it in every USB port I have available, and I've also changed the setting in the "policies" page of the device manager to optimize for speed. The file is stored locally on the drive, and I'm not noticing anything odd with disk or CPU activity. I'm not entirely sure if the port I've got it plugged into (which is directly on the MB and not on a front header/panel) is 2.0 or 1.1 but even with 1.1 shouldn't I be seeing speeds of at least 10 MBps?

What could be the bottleneck here? I note that pretty much every question similar to this one has gone unanswered on SU.

Comment: Maybe helpful: http://superuser.com/q/123176/76571

Comment: Or better yet: http://superuser.com/questions/147980/slow-transfer-with-memory-stick-819-kb-s

Comment: My drive is already FAT32, plugged directly into the mobo and so far as I can tell its USB 2.0 because I don't get the usual "this device could perform faster if plugged into a USB 2.0 port" warning. Besides, like I said even if USB 2.0 was turned off shouldn't I be getting at least 5-10 MBps and not 600 kbps?

Comment: USB 1.1 has max rates 12Mbit/s. So it's possible that with overhead you could see these speeds.

Comment: You can use [CPU-Z](http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html) to find out model of your MB and then look for some specs, to verify version of your USB.

Comment: Did you try the USB flash drive on another computer? Does it work any better?  Have you tried a different USB drive on the problematic computer?  Did it work any better?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have another computer or USB drive I could test with. What are the chances of it being a faulty USB drive?